# OFFSET complexity InnoDB

Tags: mysql, time-complexity

I have question about complexity of `OFFSET` in InnoDB. I know this works mostly in linear complexity, but if I'll have index on field ?!

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE `person_rand` (
 `p_id` int(6) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
 `town_id` int NOT NULL,
 KEY p_town (town_id),
 CONSTRAINT `fk_perrand` FOREIGN KEY (p_id) REFERENCES person_data(p_id) on update cascade on delete cascade
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

and query

```
SELECT p_id FROM person_rand WHERE town_id=69 LIMIT 1 OFFSET 666
```

So how fast will be execute this query? Won't it be work in constant time?

```
EXPLAIN SELECT p_id FROM person_rand WHERE town_id=69 LIMIT 1 OFFSET 666
```

Every time shows me another number of rows

```
id  select_type     table           type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE          person_rand     ref     p_town          p_town    4         const   950     Using index
```

Comment: prepend an `EXPLAIN` and see for yourself?

Comment: I've edited post. Everytime it shows me another number of rows..

Comment: `EXPLAIN SELECT p_id FROM person_rand WHERE town_id=69 LIMIT 1` also doesn't works in constant time, but I have a key ..

Answer (score 1):

The number of rows shown in EXPLAIN is only an estimate based on InnoDB table statistics. Don't take it as a precise number.

The index search for `town_id=69` has complexity O(log<sub>2</sub>*n*), because it's searching a B-tree.

In general, using `LIMIT` with an offset has linear complexity. In your example, it has to generate a result set of 667 rows before it can skip past the offset of 666 to get the 1 row following the offset.

You can read more about how MySQL optimizes queries with `LIMIT`: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/limit-optimization.html